# Check if a specific process is active and kill it

Tags: vbscript

I need a .vbs file to check if a specific process is active and (if it is) terminate it.

Comment: I saw that one but I need **to check if a specific process is active** ... and (if it is) terminate it... In that particular example I could not see the part related to checking the existence of a specific active process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as this thread?

[How to terminate process using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893237/how-to-terminate-process-using-vbscript)

Except that you just change the following line:

```
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'Process.exe'")
```

to

```
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & strMyProcess  & "'")
```

Comment: I did replace that line as you suggested but I must have done something wrong. Could you please tell me if/how the section **& strMyProcess  &** needs to be edited assuming I want to kill a process called "KM Player.exe"

Comment: Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'KMPlayer.exe'")

Answer (score 0):

```
    myProcess="chrome.exe"                     'repleace chrome.exe with your process name
    Set Processes = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
    For Each Process In Processes
        If StrComp(Process.Name, myProcess, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 'check if process exist
           Process.Terminate()                                   'kill the process you find
        End If
    Next
```