# how do i search for a running program with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

i want to write a script that when excecuted it will search for a specific file or program and if it's not open for the code to open that file. I'm in school bored and want to have my e-textbook automatically open on logon(i figured out running the script from login) when its not running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a specific process is active and kill it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12986207/692942)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a code for you but I do have a way for you to open any program and or file from the startup.

---

1. Open RUN --- By holding down the windows key and pressing R.
2. Type the following in to RUN `shell:startup`
   It will open a folder.
3. Make a shortcut of the file/program and move it into the opened folder.

---

That is it next time you switch your PC on it will run it automatically.